# SpriteKit Swift 2 Actions: spawning enemy waves

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skaction, completion

I'm trying to spawn waves of enemies in a SpriteKit Game.
I thought this code would work. how do I make `runAllWaves()` wait for each wave to complete before calling the next one? (I realize if all else fails i can just increase the waveWait time artificially to count from the beginning instead of the end of each wave)

```
import SpriteKit

let waveWait =  [5, 10, 10] // pause before each wave
let waveCount = [10, 20, 50] // num. of enemies in each wave
let waveDelay = [3, 2, 1] // pause before each enemy spawns
let waveHealth = [1, 2, 3] // enemy health for each wave

var index:Int = 0

var spawn = SKAction()
var delay = SKAction()
var spawndelay = SKAction()
var repeatspawndelay = SKAction()
var wait = SKAction()
var dowave = SKAction()

var doAllWaves = SKAction()


class GameScene: SKScene {

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        print("begin!")

         runAllWaves()
    }

    func runWave(index:Int){

        spawn = SKAction.runBlock({ self.spawnEnemy(index) })
        delay = SKAction.waitForDuration(NSTimeInterval(waveDelay[index]))
        spawndelay = SKAction.sequence([spawn, delay])
        repeatspawndelay = SKAction.repeatAction( spawndelay , count: waveCount[index])

        self.runAction(repeatspawndelay)

    }

    func runAllWaves(){
        runAction(SKAction.sequence([
            SKAction.waitForDuration(NSTimeInterval(waveWait[index])),
            SKAction.runBlock({ self.runWave(index)  }) ]),
            completion: {
                index += 1
                if index < 3 { self.runAllWaves() }})
    }

    func spawnEnemy(index:Int){ print("spawn enemy with health: " + String(waveHealth[index])) }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you implement a `runNextWave` functionality and call that at the end of `runWave`? You have arrays that define each wave's attributes; if the 1st element in the array determines that wave's attributes then during `runWave` you could remove those entries and at the end of `runWave` simply call `runWave` again until the arrays are empty or some other condition is met.